# How to make init script print "OK" only when all subprocesses are stopped?

Tags: process, kill

I have a very complex python application. It has it's own init script, but when I execute:

```
sudo service my_service_daemon stop
```

It prints "Stopping my_service_daemon   [OK]", but in real subprocesses still alive, until they finish their work (they caught signal 15, but have to finish some job). So, I want that message "[OK]" will be printed only when there are no subprocesses at all.
Here is part of init script (it runs on CentOS 6)

```
...

. /etc/init.d/functions 

...

stop(){
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    if [ -a $pidfile ]; then
    group_id=$(ps -o pgid= $(cat $pidfile) | grep -o [0-9]*)
    if [ ! -z $group_id ]; then
            kill -- -$group_id
        success
    fi
    else
        failure
    fi
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile $pidfile
}
```

Comment: Poll the count of `ps -o pid= --ppid $(cat $pidfile)`, maybe?

Comment: It seems like also working, could you provide some explanation? What a difference from that solution with pgrep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do the `kill -- -$group_id` wait for all the processes to end.  For example, I'd do something like

```
...
if [ ! -z "$group_id" ]; then
    kill -- -$group_id
    while pgrep -g $group_id &>/dev/null; do
        sleep 1
    done
    success
...
```

This will have `pgrep` search for all members of the process group (`-g`) `$group_id`.  Normally it will print all those PIDs to the screen, but we don't really want to see them so I redirect all the output to `/dev/null`.  `pgrep` will exit with success (`0`) if it finds at least 1 process matching its search criteria, which would keep the `while` loop going.  Once it doesn't find any processes it will exit with a "false" (`1`) which will exit the loop and get to the `success` line.  In order to not crush the system with a tight loop, I stuck a `sleep 1` in there.

Comment: It seems, like it really helps! Could you please, provide some explanation? I've never used pgrep

Comment: @Sergius I've updated my answer with some explanation of how it works

Answer (score 3):

Use `systemd`'s handling of processes, or use a `cgroup` by hand to control the zoo of decendents. Fooling around with `ps(1)` output and PID files is race-prone, and has been known to lead to early baldness due to hair-pulling.

Comment: systemd? but it has sysvinit as init system, also it's a /etc/init.d/my_service_daemon script... or I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a file open in the Python application. That is, open it in the launcher script, and don't close it in the application.

This file can be the PID file. Proof of concept (with no handling of concurrency):

```
pidfile=/var/run/myapp.pid
logfile=/var/log/myapp.log
start () {
  sh -c 'echo $$ >"$1"; exec myapp <"$1" >/dev/null 2>"$2"' &
}
stop () {
  master_pid=$(cat "$pidfile")
  while
    case " $(fuser "$pidfile" 2>/dev/null) " in
      *" $master_pid "*)
        echo "Master process is alive, killing it"
        kill "$master_pid";;
      "  ") echo "Master process is dead and no subprocesses remain"; false;;
      *) echo "Master process is already dead but some processes remain";;
    esac
  do
    sleep 1
  done
  rm "$pidfile"
}
```